# How do I sort a list by value in python?

Tags: python

I have gotten python to read a file and add the content into a list ('batman, 10', 'Iphone,900') but can't figure out how to make it sort it out so batman, 10 will be first as its number is lower and not because of its name. How can I do this?

Comment: Are you actually using a list? Or are you using a dictionary?

Answer (score 0):

you want a special key which splits the string, converts the second part to integer to pass to `sort`

```
the_tuple = ('batman, 10', 'Iphone,900')

result = sorted(the_tuple, key = lambda x : int(x.split(",")[1]))
```

You can add a tiebreaker if needed in case of a same number/different name. In that case I'd avoid `lambda` as it makes `split` repeat:

```
the_tuple = ('robin, 10', 'batman, 10', 'Iphone,900')

def sort_function(x):
    name,number = x.split(",")
    return int(number),name

result = sorted(the_tuple, key = sort_function)
```

result:

```
['batman, 10', 'robin, 10', 'Iphone,900']
```

to sort by biggest number, just add `reverse=True` to `sort` (that also reverses the tiebreaker so another option is to do `return -int(number),name` (negate the number)

Comment: Thanks it worked but how do I make it so it does the biggest number?

Comment: edit to show the possibilities